# Using svyquantile() with less than 2 non-NA values

Tags: r, error-handling, survey

I'm trying to compute the median of one (or more) variables grouped by another variable. I'm using `svyby` for it. The problem is that some groups can have less than 2 non-NA values.

I made this function to return `NA` to groups with less than 2 non-NA values, but it dosn't work:

```
require(survey)
exemplo <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, var = rnorm(10), var2 = rnorm(10, 5), grupo = factor(c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D')), peso = rchisq(10, 5))
exemplo[10, 2] <- NA
amostra <- svydesign(ids = ~ ID, data = exemplo, weights = ~ peso)

svyquantile <- function(x, design, quantiles, ...) {
    out <- try(survey::svyquantile(x = x, design = design, quantiles = quantiles, ...))
    termos <- attr(terms(x), "term.labels")
    out <- if (class(out) == "try-error") { matrix(NA, nrow = length(termos), ncol = length(quantile)) } else { out }
    colnames(out) <- quantiles
    rownames(out) <- termos
    return(out)
}
svyby(~ var + var2, ~ grupo, amostra, svyquantile, quantile = .5, na.rm = TRUE) # Não funciona
```

Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off, i don't recommend using

```
~ var + var2
```

in the survey package..  if *any* are missing, the results are missing in both.  compare:

```
svymean( ~ var + var2 , amostra , na.rm = TRUE )
svymean( ~ var2 , amostra , na.rm = TRUE )
```

instead of overwriting svyquantile, perhaps write a function that calls it if the conditions are OK?

```
myqt <- 
    function( ... ){ 

        a <- list( ... )

        this.qt <- if( is.null( a$quantile ) ) a[[3]] else a$quantile

        tt <- a[[2]]$variables

        # condition where svyquantile breaks
        if( sum( complete.cases( tt[ as.character( a[[1]] )[2] ] ) ) < 2 ){ 
            # re-create an empty svyquantile object of the same structure
            out <- matrix(rep(as.numeric(NA), length(this.qt)),nrow=1)
            dimnames(out) <- list( as.character(a[[1]])[2] , this.qt )

            # end the function
            return( out ) 

        # if svyquantile doesn't break, pass everything to it as normal
        } else svyquantile( ... )
    }
```

and note you can use this within `svyby` in place of `svyquantile`

```
# test cases

myqt( ~ var , subset( amostra , grupo %in% 'A' ) , 0.5 )
myqt( ~ var , subset( amostra , grupo %in% 'A' ) , c( 0.25 , 0.5 ) )
myqt( ~ var , subset( amostra , grupo %in% 'C' ) , 0.5 )
myqt( ~ var , subset( amostra , grupo %in% 'C' ) , c( 0.25 , 0.5 ) )

svyby(~ var , ~ grupo, amostra, myqt, quantile = 0.5 , na.rm = TRUE, keep.var=F) 
svyby(~ var , ~ grupo, amostra, myqt, quantile = c( .25 , .5 , .75 ) , na.rm = TRUE, keep.var=F)
```

Comment: For some [strange] reason, now `svyby()`  fails before call `myqt`, but works when asking `svymean` (inside `svyby`)... (This inside my function, in the example I gave it worked!). And thanks for the warning about the unexpected behavior when there is any NA.